# ClearCase check-in operation fails with: Can't close file descriptor 0: bad file descriptor

Tags: clearcase, checkin, rft

When I try to check-in an RFT script, I get this error. Undo-checkout and check-out again did not help.

When I try to check-in the rftdef file (a script dependency file) using ClearCase Explorer, I get the same error.

Any ideas?

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 0):

If the type manager "`_rftdef`" is an issue, you can try an change it to a simple text file, in order for that same type manager to not be triggered.

```
 cleartool chtype -force text_file FinansBanka.rftdef
```

That is a workaround solution, which doesn't address while the type manager fails in the first place.
For that, I would recommend to try with a shorter, simpler version of `FinansBanka.rftdef`, to see if its content got corrupted somehow.

---

As the [Cagin Uludamar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1728856/cagin-uludamar) [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23131028/6309), a discrepancy between:

- the version of the ClearCase client
- the version of the ClearCase server

can be the cause of a type manager not functioning properly.

See "[About the Rational ClearCase Type Manager](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27009697)":

> For operations that create/delete/modify source containers (cleartool/GUI/multitool-import mkelem,mkbranch,checkin,checkout-w/auto-mkbranch,rmver,rmbranch,rmelem), the type manager runs as a child process of `cleartool`/GUI/`multitool-import`.

Once that source container (run by an older client) is managed by the view server (on a more recent server), trouble can ensue.

Trigger definitions and magic files are two resources that must be deployed coherently both on the ClearCase server and clients.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that our computer is Win7 Enterprise, but ClearCase v7.0. Uninstalled it, installed CC v7.1.2 and the problems have disappeared.

Comment: Good catch. I have included documentation in my answer for that case.